# Creating filter for SPAlert Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We are creating SPAlert programmatically in Sharepoint 2007 portal.
We are facing issue while creating CAML query for eight parameters to filter.
The mail is getting triggered for filter on two or one parameter.

Below is the alert.Filter query for eight parameters but not getting what I am doing wrong

```
<Query>
  <Or>
    <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='consulting' /><ValueType='Text'>cbYes</Value></Eq>
      <Or>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='consulting1' /><Value Type='Text'>cbNo</Value></Eq>
        <Or>
          <Eq><FieldRef Name='tags' /><Value Type='Text'>strTags</Value></Eq>
          <Eq><FieldRef Name='domain' /><Value Type='Text'>strDomain</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
      </Or>
    </Or>
    <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='consulting' /><ValueType='Text'>cbYes</Value></Eq>
      <Or>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='stype' /><Value Type='Text'>strContentSubType</Value></Eq>
        <Or>
          <Eq><FieldRef Name='vertical' /><Value Type='Text'>strSubVertical</Value></Eq>
          <Eq><FieldRef Name='account' /><Value Type='Text'>strAccount</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
      </Or>
    </Or>
  </Or>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might just be a typo in the question but the 2 lines that read:

```
<FieldRef Name='consulting' /><ValueType='Text'>cbYes</Value>
```

Should have a space between 'Value' and 'Type' like so:

```
<FieldRef Name='consulting' /><Value Type='Text'>cbYes</Value>
```

Comment: yes that is a typo in the question.
and Thank you for taking time to understand my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the Query tag.

Comment: Edit your OP to reflect EXACTLY what you've got in code mate. I can't tell whether it's a typo in this post or what.

Comment: The `Query` element *is* closed. The code just wasn't formatted properly.